# andorid:ScrollView Jerky and animation list not work

Tags: android, animation, android-scrollview

My device is HTC ONE, some strange issues on this device.

1 Frame animation like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon1"
        android:duration="250">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon2"
        android:duration="250">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon3"
        android:duration="250">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon4"
        android:duration="250">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon5"
        android:duration="250">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon6"
        android:duration="250">
    </item>
</animation-list>
```

it works well on other devices, but doesn't work on HTC ONE

2 I'm using a ScrollView and a custom view inside it. The scroll animation of the view is very jerky. also on HTC ONE

It does make me crazy. Could you give me a hand?! or give me some advices. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, hardware acceleration may be a solution